# Saving long term configuration from a web application

Tags: python, django, web-applications

I am currently working on a small scale web application in Django, which will be integrated with a microcontroller.
All the data gathered by the application is saved in an SQL database.
Some of the data will be changed and accessed frequently (e.g. user data, permissions etc.), however - other data (microcontroller configuration for example) will be changed rarely, and accessed frequently by the backend code which works with the microcontroller.
I don't want the microcontroller code to access the database each time to sample its configuration parameters. However, I also don't want to change it directly from the web application (this will break the interface through which I update all other entries in the site).
So far I thought about caching, however - there might be a simpler solution I'm missing...

Answer (score 0):

Use DB caching :

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/cache/#database-caching

or memcache in the same article